# Animated TV series with a boy who has a half broken sword who sails to look for 12 or 13 mystical gems

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

It was a fantasy world of a kid that went sailing into the sea looking for some magic gems. The kid had a sword that looked half broken and the antagonist was some sort of monster that used one of its minions to infiltrate the protagonist ship to gain its trust and steal the gems.

In the end that minion turned to the good side. It was like the feeble coward creature if I remember correctly.

Comment: Sounds like one of those video games where the awesome, powerful, nearly unbeatable boss joins you and proves to be largely ineffective against anyone else.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?

Comment: i was really REALLY young. it had to be around the early 90's but not sure if the series could be from that period or maybe a bit older...

Comment: I have marked your question as a Duplicate. That does not mean that it is a bad question, just one that we've had before (specifically for story-id that we have the answer as a confirmed one). You will still get points for upvotes, but no more answers can be provided.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [Pirates of Dark Water](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pirates_of_Dark_Water).

> Ren, the son of the dying King Primus of Octopon, sails around the alien world of Mer on a ship called the Wraith, searching for the "Thirteen Treasures of Rule". The treasures are prophesied to save Octopon and Mer from the threat of Dark Water, an all-consuming black liquid that has taken over the seas. His loyal crew of misfits that help Ren on his journey are the ecomancer Tula, a monkey-bird Niddler, and the treasure-hungry pirate Ioz. Ren's opponent in his quest is the pirate Bloth of the warship the Maelstrom, who will stop at nothing to get the treasures and control the Dark Water himself.

Comment: I loved that show as a kid. Why'd you have to beat me to an answer?

Comment: The half broken sword: https://youtu.be/t4v9mlZQNgE

Comment: that sword looks very much a like what i remember